VSCode Flutter auto-formatting else on the same line as closing bracket?
I am new to flutter and have recently installed VSCode + the official Flutter plugin and I want to turn off the part of the auto-formatter that reformats else clauses to be on the same line as the closing bracket of the if statement.
E.g. I write this (and want it to stay like this):
void toggleFavorite() {
  if (favorites.contains(current)) {
    favorites.remove(current);
  }
  else {
    favorites.add(current);
  }
}

But it gets refactored to this:
void toggleFavorite() {
  if (favorites.contains(current)) {
    favorites.remove(current);
  } else {
    favorites.add(current);
  }
}

I tried both google and searching SO but could only find things for VS (not code) or for plugins for other languages, nothing for VSC+Flutter/Dart
